# Covert html form to pdf when clicking submit button using php

Tags: php, html, pdf

Please Help me out As i m new to php!! 
 I have a site with  html form of filling the details of a student.  I need this: when user clicks on  submit button it as to show the details filled in the form in  form of  pdf as well as it as to be sent the same pdf form by e-mail. Please help me with the code how to do this using php.

Thank you

Comment: Try This link `http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php`

Answer (score 0):

you can also try by TCPDF(library) which is currently the most stable version. Here is the clean example of what you are looking for.

```
<?php

require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 049');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 049', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

]$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();


$html = '<h1>Test TCPDF Methods in HTML</h1>
<h2 style="color:red;">IMPORTANT:</h2>
<span style="color:red;">If you are using user-generated content, the tcpdf tag can be unsafe.<br />
You can disable this tag by setting to false the <b>K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML</b> constant on TCPDF configuration file.</span>
<h2>write1DBarcode method in HTML</h2>';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 39', 'C39', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array('CODE 128', 'C128', '', '', 80, 30, 0.4, array('position'=>'S', 'border'=>true, 'padding'=>4, 'fgcolor'=>array(0,0,0), 'bgcolor'=>array(255,255,255), 'text'=>true, 'font'=>'helvetica', 'fontsize'=>8, 'stretchtext'=>4), 'N'));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="write1DBarcode" params="'.$params.'" />';

$html .= '<tcpdf method="AddPage" /><h2>Graphic Functions</h2>';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(0));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="SetDrawColor" params="'.$params.'" />';

$params = TCPDF_STATIC::serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(50, 50, 40, 10, 'DF', array(), array(0,128,255)));
$html .= '<tcpdf method="Rect" params="'.$params.'" />';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('example_049.pdf', 'I');

?>
```